# using System.Drawing not working in C# when executed in Linux Environment

Tags: c#, epplus, system.drawing, excel-automation

I am generating an excel programmatically, but it works fine in VS, when I tried automating it and compiling via Linux environment, it shows error.

`
using System.Drawing;

ws1.View.FreezePanes(2, 1);

var allCells = ws1.Cells[ws1.Dimension.Address];
allCells.AutoFilter = true;

// Auto-fit all the columns
allCells.AutoFitColumns();`

Not working in Linux Environment. Is there a way to make this work ?

Is there an Alternative to using System.Drawing; library ?

Comment: Be careful with undoing other users improvements to the formatting of your post. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: We hade the same issue, and ended up using https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp, since the two other in the MS documentation are in preview. I don't know if they support what you are looking for. 

Ms documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only